# I can't create a new project with java language anymore on Android Studio Flamingo?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I updated my android studio to the flamingo version today, and I found it strange that there is no longer an option to select languages on the new project screen. Is this a bug? did I do something wrong? Or is there really no more support for the java language in Flamingo? How can I resolve this?

Thanks for any help! Unfortunately I didn't find any answer to this problem on the internet.

[image: new project options]

I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

On **Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1**, you can select **Empty Views Activity** when creating a new project as shown below.
[image]

And you can still choose the **Java** or **Kotlin** language as usual.
[image]

Comment: Agree with this answer, the empty activity and empty views activity is different. To use java, choose empty views activity. Thx.

Comment: Choosing any other activity other than Empty View Activity doesn't provide the option to select Java

Comment: FYI: seems to be the same in Hedgehog

Answer (score 18):

I can see it, probably you have chosen the templates for a compose activity which now are the default ones, if the app is in compose it can only use kotlin and I guess that's why if the compose option is selected it doesn't allow you to choose java then.

After selecting **Empty Activity** (in compose):

[image]

After selecting one of the traditional views options like the **Basic Views Activity**:

[image]

Comment: Oh, it's true! I hadn't noticed that the view patterns had changed. For a moment I thought that java was deprecated for android development.

Thanks a lot for your help buddy!!!!

Answer (score 7):

I am using **Android Studio Flamingo** version. I also encountered the same issue. You should use other pre-defined activities to be able to select language type.

*Ex: Empty Views Activity, Basic Views Activity, Bottom Navigation Views Activity etc.*

**Note:**

- **Empty Activity** and **Empty Views Activity** are different
- Empty/Basic... **Activity:** uses Jetpack Compose for UI rendering
- Empty/Basic... **Views Activity:** uses XML based layouts and also provides us options to choose for Java or Kotlin language selection

I have attached a screenshot of it too.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Till the moment I always used Empty Activity because I wanted the project clean and only put in it the things I wanted. With Basic Views Activity it generates too much unwanted features (2 fragments, 2 layouts for activity). I am absolutely lost with this new version and cannot find  Electric Eel (the version I used before) anywhere to downgrade Android.

Comment: Check out https://developer.android.com/studio/archive